# For returning Option from pattern matching, use Try?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have lots of pattern matching code that looks as follows: If some `Foo` matches, a `Some` of `Bar` is returned, otherwise `None`, and there are lots of `Foos` and long constructors for `Bars`. Something like:

```
y match {
   case Foo1(z) => Some(Bar1(z))
   case Foo2(z) => Some(Bar2(z))
   case Foo3(z) => Some(Bar3(z))
   case Foo4(z) => Some(Bar4(z))
   case _ => None
}
```

In the actual code, the constructors on the right hand side of the arrows are more complex, and there are more cases.

Now, in order to get rid of the repetitive option constructors (`Some`), I could do:

```
Try( 
   y match {
     case Foo1(z) => Bar1(z)
     case Foo2(z) => Bar2(z)
     case Foo3(z) => Bar3(z)
     case Foo4(z) => Bar4(z)
  }
).toOption
```

This looks significantly cleaner to me, and from a semantic perspective it is justifiable, as the `case _` is actually a situation that should not occur, thus modeling it as an exception seems justifiable. Note that it is the repetitive `Somes` that bug me, not the last `case`.

My question is whether there is some (e.g. performance) penalty to the latter approach I am not aware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second version is less readable, and less correct*. There isn't much of a point in using `Try` if you're just going to discard the error to `None`. The `Try` is *only* there to catch match errors and convert them to `None`, but you can do that in one like with `case _ => None`.

There would be slightly more overhead wrapping in `Try`, but not enough to matter. Correctness and readability should come first.

If you *really* don't want to have that extra case, consider wrapping `y` in `Option` and using `collect`:

```
Option(y) collect {
   case Foo1(z) => Bar1(z)
   case Foo2(z) => Bar2(z)
   case Foo3(z) => Bar3(z)
   case Foo4(z) => Bar4(z)
}
```

Using `collect` on an `Option` will wrap the cases in the partial function that are defined in `Some`, and any cases that do not match will become `None`.

---

*By *correct*, I mean widely accepted use of `Try`.

Comment: My very point is readability (which is not as objective as you make it sound) and it is the additional Some's which I find distracting, not the last case statement. Will your version handle the unmatched case? In case it does, I find it a very nice solution. I see your point about Try.

Comment: My point about readability is that wrapping the `match` in `Try` obscures its very purpose, and yes. I will edit in more detail.